# Does an ultra-relativistic electron's $\vec E$ field carry energy off to infinity?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, classical-electrodynamics

I am curious: The $\vec{E}$ field for an ultra-relativistic charge is defined in the radial direction (cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ as:

$$\vec{E}_r=\frac{-2e}{r}\delta(z-ct) $$

for a charge with its velocity all along the z-axis. So, is this is a sense a radiation field because of the $\frac 1 r$ behavior akin to the radiation portion of the Lienard Wiechert field?

Comment: See [these lecture notes](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node125.html). In the ultra relativistic limit, the fields look like a pulse plane wave traveling in the same direction, and with the same speed, as the point charge. So no energy is carried off to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a stationary charge whose electric field follows coulombs law. If we integrate the energy flux of the electric field through a bounding surface at infinity we obtain zero.

Now perform a Lorentz transformation on that problem akin to that in your question, one should still obtain zero.

I believe the ambiguity here lies in the fact that the electric field is essentially infinitely "thin" in the z-direction which makes the flux of the 1/r field still yield zero. (apologies, my phone isn't equation friendly) For example Gauss' law still applies here normally as one just integrates over a closed loop with element rdtheta (zero everywhere else)

Also note that is an asymptotic expression for the limit of light speed, in reality such a situation is physically impossible.